# Legal restrictions if using Google Analytics on PC game?

Tags: legal, pc, analytics

I'm thinking of using Google Analytics to collect various user information (including hardware information) in my PC desktop game I'm making with Unity.I figured I can do this by setting up a new tracking property and using Measurement Protocol to send hits to Google Analytics using HTTP.

Are there any legal restrictions on this? After all, I will be collecting hardware information along with gamer behavior. Do I need to inform the user and / or ask for their allowance for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think, that you are allowed to collect userdata, without the allowance of the player.
But you should have a look at 
http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/gb.html
or
http://www.google.com/analytics/terms (for more languages).

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to notify the user and he has to accept, if the user don't want his data collected and you do it anyways you could be in troubles.

Analytics is not the problem, the problem is collecting data without explicit permission.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a personal opinion or can you point me to any legal documentation regarding this?

Comment: @A.BurakErbora I'ts the legislation here in Spain at least, i can't point you anywhere but that's how it's done in the industry here, usually there's a dislaimer in the software installer.